# Problem with popup Error: "-1300 from iMacros

Tags: web, stack, imacros

I have this problem when I run a code from imacros. The code is the following:

```
VERSION BUILD=2021
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2
URL GOTO=https://matricula.sise.edu.pe/admin/dashboard/disponibles
EVENT TYPE=click SELECTOR="#\3667278" BUTTON=0 POINT=(341,263)
EVENT TYPE=click SELECTOR="#table-students>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(1)>div>label" BUTTON=0 POINT=(167,260)
EVENT TYPE=click SELECTOR="#STABE011063" BUTTON=0 POINT=(167,260)
EVENT TYPE=click SELECTOR="body>app-root>app-admin>app-dashboard>div>div.container-2.mx-auto>div>div.col-md-10.p-2>app-disponibles>ngx-smart-modal:nth-child(2)>div>div>div>div>div.p-2.header-modal>div.btn-close.d-flex>a>i" BUTTON=0 POINT=(1318,192)
```

What the code does is click in the small box next to each course name (same as in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbqX0.png)) then a pop-up box [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU8RC.png) should appear and continue.

But when I run it I get the following error from the first line:

**Error: "-1300: ElementNotFound" at line 6
EVENT TYPE=click SELECTOR="#\3667278" BUTTON=0 POINT=(341,263)
Could not find element**

The popup simply does not appear. When I try with TAG only the box remains marked without the popup appearing.

```
VERSION BUILD=2021
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2
URL GOTO=https://matricula.sise.edu.pe/admin/dashboard/disponibles
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:667278 CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:STABE011063 CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:"fa fa-times text-white text-l"
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Images:

[Error Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbqX0.png)

[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU8RC.png)

Comment: The ID on the 1st CB looks dynamic to me ("3667278" in your `EVENT` Mode Script, but "667278" in your `TAG` Mode Script) although the Check seems to work on that 1st CB with the `TAG` Script... Many "Things" could be playing a Role, with different Suggestions to troubleshoot your Issue, not very "easy" with short Comments on this Site as I won't have a "straightforward" Solution to post as "Answer", I think you could better open a Thread on the [iMacros Forum](https://forum.imacros.net/) where it will be easier to help you... (Mod there, make sure to read the Forum Rules...)

Comment: + Remove (or sbd with 2k(+) Rep) the [tag:web] + [tag:stack] Tags, you didn't read their Descriptions, but they are completely useless/unrelated to your Thread, especially the `stack` one... (Selecting "wrong"/random Tags on SO is the "best way" to get Downvotes on your Qt, just saying..., as it is annoying for (Advanced) Users in those Tags as they will receive a "false" Notif about your Qt... I'm nearly surprised it hasn't happened yet...)